# Submit the build of iPhone app to iTunes app store

Tags: iphone, submit, app-store-connect

I work for iPhone app but this is the first time I submit iPhone app to app store. I pass all request from iTunes, but the at the step Build the app, I don't know how to build and submit my build to iTunes.
[image]

I have Apple developer account, and I can build the app to my iPhone device. I am using Xcode 6.1. But I don't know how to submit my build to iTunes as this requirement. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using XCode6.1 you can submit your build using Application Loader.

> Open XCode Menu -> Open Developer Tools -> (Select) Application Loader

That's it, and follow the instruction.

You may need to read,
[Submitting the App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html).

Comment: Thanks Hemang, but at the step Template chooser in Application Loader, I don't know which file will be choose or imported.

Comment: You should import your zip file (contains an `ipa`) file.

Comment: Now I submit the ipa success via Application Loader. But in iTunes, I cannot "Submit for Review", it also inform that I need to submit the build. What is next step? Thank you.

Comment: Ok great, now you've to create an app in iTunes first, where you've to select the build (ipa) which you've uploaded. Also if possible, please read the link in my answer, its having everything.

Comment: Thank you very much, Hemang. After I refresh iTunesconnect page, I can choose the build. It is OK now.